# Generating generic multiplication problems in Python

Tags: python, math

So far I've created code that generates 5 variable (where 'o' is a variable) multiplication problems, such that every possible combination of grouping symbols is shown. This works fine so far, but if I were to change my number of variables (to 6, or 3 for example), I would need to add yet another nearly identical for loop at the end of the last one. I'm trying to find a way where it will do this automatically based on a variable entered by the user.

```
group = []
a = '( o * o )'

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 'o':
        b = (a[:i] + a + a[i+1:])
        for l in range(len(b)):
            if b[l] == 'o':
                c = (b[:l] + a + b[l+1:])
                for j in range(len(c)):
                    if c[j] == 'o':
                        d = (c[:j] + a + c[j+1:])
                        group.append(d)
group = list(set(group))
for i in range(len(group)):
    print(group[i])
```

Output:

```
( ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) * o )
( ( o * o ) * ( o * ( o * o ) ) )
( o * ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) )
( ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) * o )
( ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) * o )
( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * ( o * o ) )
( o * ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) )
( o * ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) )
( ( o * o ) * ( ( o * o ) * o ) )
( ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) * o )
( o * ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) )
( o * ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) )
( ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) * o ) 
( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * ( o * o ) )
```

Comment: Try write functions with recursion that has depth parameter in it. When the depth reach 0, you output the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion. Note that the parameter `n` means the level of depth, and since there are two variables in the atomic group `( o * o )`, `n` should be 2 less than the number of variables you wish to get the multiplication group combinations on.

```
a = '( o * o )'
def g(n):
    if n == 0:
        return {a}
    r = set()
    for b in g(n - 1):
        for i in range(len(b)):
            if b[i] == 'o':
                r.add(b[:i] + a + b[i + 1:])
    return r
for n in range(5):
    print(g(n))
```

This outputs:

```
{'( o * o )'}
{'( ( o * o ) * o )', '( o * ( o * o ) )'}
{'( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o )', '( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) )', '( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) )', '( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o )'}
{'( ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) * o )', '( ( o * o ) * ( ( o * o ) * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) )', '( ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) * o )', '( ( o * o ) * ( o * ( o * o ) ) )', '( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * ( o * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) )', '( ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) * o )', '( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * ( o * o ) )', '( o * ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) )', '( ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) * o )', '( ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) * o )', '( o * ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) )', '( o * ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) )'}
{'( o * ( ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) * o ) )', '( ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * ( o * o ) ) * o )', '( ( o * o ) * ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) )', '( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * ( o * ( o * o ) ) )', '( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * ( ( o * o ) * o ) )', '( ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) * ( o * o ) )', '( o * ( ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) ) )', '( ( o * o ) * ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) )', '( ( o * o ) * ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) )', '( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * ( ( o * o ) * o ) )', '( ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * ( o * o ) ) * o )', '( ( o * ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) ) * o )', '( ( ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) * o ) * o )', '( o * ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * ( o * o ) ) )', '( ( ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) * o ) * o )', '( o * ( ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) * o ) )', '( ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) * ( o * o ) )', '( o * ( ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) ) )', '( ( ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) * o ) * o )', '( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * ( o * ( o * o ) ) )', '( ( ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) * o ) * o )', '( ( ( o * o ) * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) * o )', '( ( o * ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) ) * o )', '( ( o * ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) ) * o )', '( ( ( o * o ) * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) * o )', '( ( o * o ) * ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) )', '( ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) * ( o * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) ) )', '( ( o * ( ( o * o ) * ( o * o ) ) ) * o )', '( o * ( o * ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) ) )', '( ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) * ( o * o ) )', '( ( o * o ) * ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) )', '( o * ( o * ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) ) )', '( o * ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * ( o * o ) ) )', '( o * ( ( o * o ) * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) )', '( o * ( ( o * o ) * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) )', '( ( o * ( o * ( o * ( o * o ) ) ) ) * o )', '( o * ( ( o * ( ( o * o ) * o ) ) * o ) )', '( ( ( ( o * ( o * o ) ) * o ) * o ) * o )', '( ( ( ( o * o ) * o ) * o ) * ( o * o ) )'}
```

Comment: A little tinkering and this works perfectly, thank you very much.